# dns01 validation: Certificate issuance in progress. Temporary certificate issued

Tags: lets-encrypt, cert-manager, knative-serving, knative, googledns

Following [this](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/using-cert-manager-on-gcp/)

Setup:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-19T22:12:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.7-gke.10", GitCommit:"8d9b8641e72cf7c96efa61421e87f96387242ba1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-12T22:59:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

knative-serve & Istio is v0.5.2
cert-manager is v0.7 applyed with --validate=false as k8s is 1.12.7
```

Cert-manager ClusterIssuer status:

```
│  status:                                                                                                                                                                           │
│    conditions:                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    - lastTransitionTime: "2019-04-29T21:29:40Z"                                                                                                                                    │
│      message: Certificate issuance in progress. Temporary certificate issued.                                                                                                      │
│      reason: TemporaryCertificate                                                                                                                                                  │
│      status: "False"                                                                                                                                                               │
│      type: Ready
```

I have done as in the documentation, but setting up Google DNS not described

I have manually created a DNS in Google DNS consule.

My domain is pointing at the nameservers and I can ping the right server ip address,

When creating the DNS I added a record set:

```
*.mydomain.com. A   300 x.x.x.x
```

Note: also tried without " * "

I have seen [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-dns-01-challenge/28593), that they talk abaout setting TXT?

Do you know how to make this(cert-manager & TLS) it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look at the logs being issued by the cert manager pod `kubectl logs -n <namespace> pod/podname`.

Cert manager will tell you why the challenge is failing.

One common reason is the rate limiting by Letsencrypt and you have to wait for 7 days.

You can also view this same issue on github https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1745